# Can you pay the B1/B2 visa fee for someone else?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, spouses, payment

For the wife's US B1/B2 visa, can the husband pay the visa fee from his account?

Comment: I don't think it matters who pays for the visa fee, as long as the payment documents reflects the person who is applying.

Answer (score 3):

Yes [someone else can pay for one's visa application](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/vn/vn-gen-faq.asp#qlistgen18):

> ### Q.18 I do not have an internet bank account. Can somebody else pay for me?
>
> If you don’t have internet account you can use another online bank account (For example, your relatives or friends).

Just make sure that the visa application details are correct i.e. those of the person applying for the visa and not those of whomever pays it.